# Using bluetooth in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, bluetooth

I am trying to create an android app with Android Studio, which shows a website from app's assetes, which includes the javascript code `navigator.bluetooth.getDevices()`, in a WebView. When I add a try catch block around this functioncall in the javascript code and show the error message on the website, it shows me that navigator.bluetooth is undefined.

When I was looking for a solution for this, I found a recommendation to use XWalkView. But this is no longer available. A further recommendation was to use CustomTabsIntent. But when I use the same Uri as for the Webview ("file:///android_asset/index.html") the browser is not shown (for testing I used "https://www.example.com", than this page was shown).

Has anyone a solution for showing a local website, which uses bluetooth, in an Android app?

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Sorry, ``navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice()`` was just for testing. I want to use ``navigator.bluetooth.getDevices()``. But it does not matter because navigator.bluetooth is undefined and thus none of them can be used.

Comment: LOL......"getDevices()" is not supported by most of browsers......Why do not check its usability before trying to use it in a super-secured context like a WebView? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth/getDevices#browser_compatibility)

Comment: @emandt: Thank you for your very constructive and helpfull replays!
Has anyone other some experience with this topic and can help me?

Comment: As an intermediate solution I converted the website to a PWA, installed it on the mobile phone and used adb to extract the apk from this.

Comment: WebView App (the internal one) can execute and share data withing Java code, but it requires to do an additional "layer" between what is INSIDE and what is running outside it. You could create methods as getters/setters and the call them via Javascript from the WebView......it's one solution.